# Nesting Redux Providers

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to distribute a React App as a React component. Currently it uses Redux to manage its state. If the end user also uses Redux to manage the state, there will be nested Providers. Would it be a problem or should I pass the store as a prop as Dan suggested [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/304)? I personally do not like the second way tho.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think multiple redux stores isn't great. If I were you, I would provide consumers of your package with the reducer and related actions that they can attach to their own redux setup, like `react-router-redux` and other packages do

Comment: @azium thanks for the suggestion. But I don't want to force the consumers to use Redux and in my opinion, creating a redux binding kinda overcomplicates stuff. Why do you think having two redux stores are not great? One of them is completely encapsulated tho

Comment: I agree with @azium. You shouldn't need multiple stores if you are structuring your app's data the way Redux was meant to be used. I'd recommend either keeping the component's state self-contained or exposing a reducer and actions (but hiding their implementation) for consumers to use.

Comment: @lpan did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I don't remember what I did but I think pass the store via props is the best solution.

Answer (score 18):

As you're building a component to be consumed like any other black-box components, using redux internally and your own `<Provider>` is a fine option.

This will hide the parent app's store from your component but you don't want to access it anyways; it may not exist. Any data you want must be passed in through your top-level component's props.

Likewise, you don't want the parent-application to get data from your internal Redux store through Redux and you don't want any actions to go through both stores as there could easily be name conflicts and unwanted side effects.

Most people only think of Redux as an application-level state management solution and thus the negative comments. In your case your component is big enough to have a component-wide state management solution, and thus Redux for your component is appropriate.

All that said, I realize this post is several years old, so this answer is for others that stumble across this question (as I did). I would be interested in hearing in a comment what you ended up doing and how it worked out.